# Pandas: how to sum dynamically varying columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a new column where each row is the sum of the row values in the chosen columns. Please note that the number of columns are not fixed. It varies dynamically.
Say I have this dataframe and a list where I specify the columns to be added:
(The actual number of columns are much higher)

```
df
           col1  col2  col3  col4
        0    56    22   320   300
        1    34    25   220   220
        2    45    27   120   120
        3    78    35   830    83


   add = ['col1', 'col4']
```

The add list varies. I then want a new column where each row is the sum of the row values in the chosen columns, specified in add.
Something like this:

```
for col in add:
    df['sum'] += df[col]
```

And the desired result:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4  sum
0    56    22   320   300  356
1    34    25   220   220  254
2    45    27   120   120  165
3    78    35   830    83  161
```

but the above code is not working. Any hints?

Comment: just `df['Sum'] = df[add].sum(axis=1)` ? no loops required here

Comment: All right. That was simple!

Answer (score 1):

Sum along the columns

```
add = ['col1', 'col4']
df['Sum'] = df[add].sum(axis=1)
```

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4  sum
0    56    22   320   300  356
1    34    25   220   220  254
2    45    27   120   120  165
3    78    35   830    83  161
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try it without using 'for' loop by simply using df['col1','col2'].sum()  and then merging the 'sum' column with the existing dataframe .